# Cellular chain complex of $G$-CW-complexes & their differentials

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homology, equivariant-cohomology, cw-complexes

I not completly understand EXAMPLE 2.31 (page 19) dealing with homology of
$G$-CW-complexes. Source: http://www.ltcc.ac.uk/media/london-taught-course-centre/documents/LTCC-notes-Lecture3-2019.pdf

Recall, the cooking recipe for cellular homology
in case classical CW-complexes without any $G$-structure.

$X$ is $k$-dimensional CW-complex if
we have a decomposition $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset ... \subset X_{n-1} \subset X_n=X$
where every $X_{i+j}$ arises as pushforward of $X_j$
after attatching $I_j$ many $j$ cells $\cong D^j$ along $S^{j-1} \subset D^j$ to $X_j$.
The we build a cellular chain complex

$$C_k(X) \to C_{k-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\text{d}} ... \to C_1(X) \xrightarrow{\text{d}} C_0(X) \to 0$$

where $C_j := \bigoplus_{i \in I_j} \mathbb{Z}$ is free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $I_j$ and $d$-degree maps. Then compute homology
of this complex.

My **question** is if we now would like to compute cellular homology of a $G$-CW-complex
how the $C_j(X)$ would look like. Would they also be free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules or
will they have additional structure? Maybe as  $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules?
The reason why I worry about this is following example 2.31:

[image]

Consider EXAMPLE 2.31. We deal with finite cyclic group $G:= \mathbb{Z}/n$ that act on circle $S^1$ considered
as $G$-CW-CW-complex with $n$ vertices ($0$-cells) and $n$ $1$-cells.
The obviuos action by $G$ is that the generator $t := \bar{1}$ of
$G$ shift the $1$-cells resp
$0$-cells conterclockwise:

[image]

Then in the example following complex is considered:

$$\mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z}G \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

Is this the analogon of cellular complex $C_k(X)  \xrightarrow{\text{d}} ...  \xrightarrow{\text{d}} C_0(X) \to 0$ from above? Then the message is $C_1(X)=C_0(X)= \mathbb{Z}G$?

Set theoretically that's fine since the number of $1$- and $0$-cells coinsides
with $\vert G \vert$ but as what are $C_j(X)$ and the cellular complex are considered?

As $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and $\mathbb{Z}G$-structure play no role for homology **or** as a proper $\mathbb{Z}G$-complex? And what are the differentials $d$ here? Maps of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules?

More generally, let $X$ is $k$-dimensional $G$-CW-complex if
we have a decomposition $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset ... \subset X_{n-1} \subset X_n=X$
of $G$-cells and assume that this $G$-CW has $I_j$ many $j$ cells.

What is $C_j(X)$ explicitly and again what are the $d$-maps of the corresoponding cellular chain complex

$$C_k(X) \xrightarrow{\text{d}} C_{k-1}(X) \xrightarrow{\text{d}} ... \to C_1(X) \xrightarrow{\text{d}} C_0(X) \to 0$$

Are they maps of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules?

Comment: The $G$-action on $X$ makes $C_\ast(X)$ into a chain complex of $\mathbb ZG$-modules. In general I recommend Brown's bible *"Cohomology of Groups".*

Comment: @ChrisGerig: Thank you for the reference. Page 14 provides precisely the answer I was looking for! That is every $C_j(X)$ is a free $\mathbb ZG$ where the number of generator coinsides with number of orbits because $G$-action on cells is free